# Who is the killer now?

Tags: mystery

One day the local police from the Stack Exchange community received a concerned call from one of the bakeshop owners nearby.

**Police:** Good Morning, this is S.E. Police. How may I help you?

**Bakeshop Employee:** Hello sir, I'm an employee in the bakeshop near the police department. I am worried about the house in front of our shop. The owner of this house is one of our best customers, and he asked me to do him a favor. He wanted me to prepare 20 pieces of our specialty bread to be picked up early in the morning. He told me that he would like for his guests to taste our bread. However, it's already the second day since he asked me and I haven't seen him. I am very  worried because he always picks up bread from us early in the morning, and he has promised to pick up his order.

**Police**: okay sir, we will send some officers to the house you are mentioning.

As the police visited the house, they tried to knock, but found that the door was open. They proceeded inside the house.

They entered the house, and tried to find the owner of the house. They found his dead body, hanging from the high ceiling of a well lit room. There were two glass windows and one of them was broken. It seemed as if something was thrown to break the window. The police that responded to the house immediately called the forensics department and started the investigation. The room was empty; there was no furniture, garbage, or any large items inside the room, only shards of broken glass and the dead body of the owner inside, the police also checked out side the the house where the broken window is and found an empty bottle of beer. broken, might be from the fall. there where also no furnitures that looked liked misplaced inside or outside of the house, the house was pretty clean.

The police checked the last contacts of the owner and found out that there were two people that the owner invited for a drink in his home, one girl and one guy. They were brougt in for interrogation, and the police asked them questions regarding the scene and what happened when they visited.

The girl admitted that they three of them had some drinks, and she also admitted that while she was drunk she happened to have a conversational fight with the owner of the house.

**Girl**: I said to him, "No! We can't be together again." I don't love him anymore, and I had brought my new boyfriend for him to meet and have a drink. I liked him and wanted to still be friends with him, but he still insisted he loved me and I couldn't handle it. I needed it to stop!

**Boy**: I was there to escort my girlfriend. Although I didn't like what he was doing to my girlfriend, I still tried to understand his feelings. But... it was too much. I had to punch him in the face to protect my girlfriend from him. He is a nuisance and he deserved to die. After the confrontation, me and my girlfriend left the house peacefully and never heard from him again.

The police are very puzzled about this bizarre crime and do not know the answer.

Now, if you can help the investigators.. **WHO IS THE KILLER?**

Bonus Question: **How was the owner Killed?**

Comment: Where were the glass shards of the broken window?

Comment: @Aura As OP mentions, the room is empty. This probably should mean that the shards are on the outside.

Comment: @Aura i have edited the story please recheck

Comment: @dmg please recheck my edit.

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 It is not clear whether there is any furniture in the room. Please revise.

Comment: @dmg The room was empty; there was no furniture, garbage, or any large items inside the room, only shards of broken glass and the dead body of the owner inside..  this is already stated in the story.

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 I'm not trying to be nitpicking. I was merely referring to your other sentence "there where also no furnitures that looked liked misplaced inside the room or outside of the house, the house was pretty clean."

Comment: @dmg sorry, it supposed to be house, the room is empty, but there are no misplaced furnitures in the house.

Comment: @User 6675636b20796f7521 does the broken window face the baker shop?

Comment: @user2428118 it was never specified as where the room is located, but if you can create a scenario from your assumption, might aswell as post it as an answer!!! :-)

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 Did the boy and girl come on the day he ordered the bread or on the next one?

Comment: You say the beer bottle "might be from the fall"  what fall?

Comment: @ChrisLively I think it means that it was not necessarily used to smash the glass and might have been thrown/dropped from the window before or after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspect its:

> Suicide and the owner try to frame it on the Girl and Boy
> Deliberately ordering 20 bread to ensuring the baker know there are people coming to his house and ensure someone will find the corpse
> It was the owner who break the window and move all the furniture out since he's the owner, he have plenty of time to prepare and do stuff without getting suspicion

How was owner killed:

> As per what one of the answer, suicide by standing on ice. The beer smashing the window is to frame the couple and also to ensure the water get evaporated

Comment: You got it right!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the

> bakeshop employee.

#### Reasons:

> He is “very worried” yet he didn't check when the customer didn't pick up the bread yesterday (even though the door isn't locked).
>
> There isn't any furniture in the room, possibly because it has been stolen.
>
> His guests for which he ordered the bread are probably the boy and the girl. But, they were invited for a drink, not for breakfast. Did he expect them to stay over? That's very unlikely.
>
> Which leads us to the question: why didn't his guests for who he ordered the bread notice he was dead?
>
> Which leads me to call the truthfulness of the baker's story into question.
>
> It wasn't suicide; the ceiling is high, and if a ladder was used by the customer it should have been carried away by someone.
>
> The broken bottle of beer may have been dropped by one of his guests (the boy or the girl) when they left.

Comment: Nc catch :-)  and facts :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that

> He committed suicide from a broken heart. Since there was no furniture and he was the bread shop's best customer we must conclude that he stood... on many loaves of bread! He threw the beer bottle at the window shortly before kicking away the crusty bread supporting his weight so that birds could get into the room and eat the bread (which worked exactly as he planned). As a bread connoisseur he didn't want any of it to go to waste, making it his parting gift to the world.
>
> The 20 pieces of bread he ordered is clearly too much bread for just 2 guests to sample. He must have ordered the bread AFTER the girl rejected him (since we are never told how long ago the guests visited him) as his last meal - pig out on delicious specialty multi-grain before pulling the plug. But after being up all night crying (nobody would be able to sleep with a planned suicide coming up) he was a total wreck and realized he can't show up at the store like this and doesn't really want any food anyway. He downed a beer and figured he might as well just get it over with.

Comment: Even if 20 stacked loaves of bread could support the weight of an adult male, I really don't think birds could devour that much in 2 days.

Comment: @Otaia You haven't seen pigeons in action. However, pigeons crap a lot, and the house was clean. That is the obvious problem with this solution.

Comment: Nice imagination.!!

Answer (score 2):

A wild guess:

> He hanged himself. The room being completely empty means that the window was broken from the inside. When he was about to jump from a chair/ladder/nightstand he kicked it so that it will fly through the window. That is why there was no furniture.

Comment: I think you got it! The OP is doing a spinoff of [my question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/murder-on-stack-exchange) which had a similar answer.

Comment: sorry guys i overlooked that problem ill revise the story

Comment: @randal'thor i have revised the story, its not that simple! xD

Answer (score 2):

I think

> He hanged himself by standing on ice slabs. Ice slabs melted and evaporated.

@Aura

> To confuse people that it is indeed not a suicide. That is the reason why he moved all the furniture so that melted water doesn't deposit anywhere. Also he tried to show as if the beer bottle was thrown in rage after heated arguments to frame the other boy.

Comment: This is possible, but how do you explain the apparent break in?

Comment: @Aura Added clarification in another spoiler