# Classic "mathematical" riddle: 101 / 50 + 0 = 1/9. Who is it, and why?

Tags: riddle

I heard this classic riddle a long long time ago and really liked it, but I'm afraid it was way too simple for you all in the format that I originally heard it, so I have tweaked it just a little:

> 101 / 50 + 0 = 1/9

The answer is the name of a person.  Who is it, and why?

hint:

> The equation is actually of the form "name = description" (or *who = why*, if you prefer).

Now that a correct answer has been given, here is the riddle as I originally heard it, suitable for any well-educated person:

> A hundred and one, divided by fifty, followed by nothing: one of nine.

Comment: Is it one word or two?

Comment: The name is one word.

Comment: @Hellion I think that the first half of the original riddle is harder than the modded one. The second half of the original is easier though.

Comment: The 101 / 50 reminded me of Gauss, myself. Except it would be * and not /.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is:

> Clio one of the 9 Muses

Why?

> In roman: 101 = CI, we put 50 = L in between to get CLI and we "add" 0 which kinda looks like "O" and we get CLIO. There are 9 muses and she is one of them so that is the reason behind 1/9.

Also:

> The roman numbers are a reference to the roman time, when the muses actually got their roles (for example Clio became the muse of history).

**Also:**

one big "thanks" to [@rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) as he provided the basis by mentioning the roman numerals in [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/8424/5610).

Comment: You are correct, sir(?)!

Comment: @Hellion, "sir" it is :) Anyway, now that this was answered, do you mind sharing the original riddle as well?

Comment: Excellent! But @Hellion saying the answer is "the name of a person" was a bit confusing - I assumed it would be an actual name, like Derek Smith, rather than a name and description.

Comment: @randal'thor, yeah, sorry about that; when I came back and looked at it, I thought perhaps I hadn't expressed that well.  Hence my first "hint".

Answer (score 8):

101/50 could be

> CIBYL (which sounds like it could be a name),

since

> 101 in Roman numerals is CI, 50 in Roman numerals is L, and the division stroke is often read as 'by'.

Comment: + 0 could be "to"

Comment: +0 could also be "no", "none", "nil" etc, with the plus just symbolizing that you're combining the words.

Comment: Or just 'o'. I like @warspyking's idea though!

Comment: Meta-information maybe, but nothing offensive or otherwise against SE guidelines. Many answers have a few lines in them that don't *really* answer the question; look at some of the answers to [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/murder-on-stack-exchange). @Doorknob really has a problem with me ... sigh ...

Comment: Hmmm... why the DV, I wonder?